# show find textbox and 2 drop down list in the same line in a mvc form using bootstrap 3

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a search box, submit button and 2 drop down boxes in the same line for ipads to large screens. If the screen is smaller than ipad size it will break in to 2 or 3 lines. I tried all samples given in [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), but no luck.
I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.Here is my code:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="abc">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "f1", @class = "form-inline" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <label class="sr-only" for="find-input">Find: </label>
            <div class="input-group ">
                <input type="text" name="filter" value="@ViewBag.filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Product or Description" id="find-input" />
                <span class="input-group-btn ">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit();">Go</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <div class="input-group ">
                    <label class="control-label " for="sort-drop-down">Sort </label>
                    @Html.DropDownList("sortColumn", ViewBag.SortColumns as SelectList, "", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control", id = "sort-drop-down" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label " for="page-size-drop-down">Show </label>
                <div class="input-group ">
                    @Html.DropDownList("pageSize", ViewBag.pageSizes as SelectList, "", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control", id = "page-size-drop-down" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="viewMode" id="hd1" value="@ViewBag.DisplayMode" />
    }
   </div>
</div>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index(int pageSize = 8, string sortColumn = "Id", string viewMode = "grid")
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        Dictionary<string, string> sortByColumnsList = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Id", "Id" }, { "ProductName", "Product Name" }, { "Description", "Description" } };
        ViewBag.SortColumns = new SelectList(sortByColumnsList, "Key", "Value", sortColumn); // NOTE: To set a default value(4) we can use: new SelectList(sortByColumnsList, "Key", "Value", "Id=4")

        //Page Sizes
        List<string> pageSizeList;
        if (viewMode.ToLower() == "table")
        {
            pageSizeList = new List<string>() { "10", "25", "50", "100" };
            if (pageSizeList.IndexOf(pageSize.ToString()) < 0)
            {
                pageSize = 10;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pageSizeList = new List<string>() { "8", "12", "16", "20" };
            if (pageSizeList.IndexOf(pageSize.ToString()) < 0)
            {
                pageSize = 8;
            }
        }
        ViewBag.pageSizes = new SelectList(pageSizeList, pageSize);

        return View();
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.abc {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Please can someone  help?

Comment: It appears that you are testing it on your laptop and not on ipad or a projector?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, I am testing in Desktop, with resizing and using tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just handled case for a large device(**col-lg**) or an extra small  device(**xs**). So when customising customise it for `md` as well i.e. **Medium Sized devices**.

> In your case just don't handle it and let outer inline-form class handle it for you.

Also, try enclosing your row within a div with class container. As I'm not much familiar with .NET, but let's say we are observing our final html page obtained.

See sample output fiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/3vnxncke/

Also, see screenshots below for same scenarios with the code by screen adjustment.

[image]

You may try adjusting html screen size to see other device scenarios.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I try your same code in pure Html (in visual studio 2013)it worked. But when I use it in MVC application it doesn't work. I even tried by create same code using razor syntax for the form. There is something else might course this problem.

Comment: Okay!So could you please check source html generated after mvc call. I am sure that there is some extra code or css lying there which is causing the problem e.g. some body or html level css changes etc. On chrome, Right click and click on `View Page Source` and observe for any issues.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it adjusting css. I have added it as an answer, hope it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If someone having same issue when using MVC templates, I would like to show what I have done to fix this issue. The correct way to use bootstrap html is described on @Vinay Prajapati's answer. Although it works for pure html page it doesn't work when we use MVC scaffolding. So I have made some `css` adjustment as follows.

```
.input-group
{
   display:inline-table;
}
.control-label{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.form-group .control-label 
{
   margin-top:-15px;
}
.input-group-btn{
   width:auto;
}
```

**Adjusted html**

```
<div class="container  body-content">
    <form class="form-inline" id="f1" method="get">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="find-input">Find: </label>
                <div class="input-group ">
                    <input type="text" name="filter" value="ViewBag.filter" class="form-control" id="find-input" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn ">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit();">Go</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label " for="sort-drop-down">Sort </label>
                <div class="input-group ">
                    <select class="form-control" id="sort-drop-down" name="sortColumn" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                        <option selected="selected" value="Id">Id</option>
                        <option value="ProductName">Product Name</option>
                        <option value="Description">Description</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label " for="sort-drop-down">Show: </label>
                <div class="input-group ">
                    <select class="form-control" id="page-size-drop-down" name="pageSize" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                        <option>16</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```